# C++ changing type in constructor?

Tags: c++, class, types, polymorphism

I have an abstract class `Engine3D` and it's structures (`Vector3D`, etc.) in the header files.

Now, I have an implementation for that class, `ConcreteEngine3D : Engine3D`. Also, I have other classes like `ConcreteVector3D : Vector3D` that have additional members and methods that will be used inside `ConcreteEngine3D` (for the sake of this example, let's say it's `float length` and `calculateLength()`).

In main.cpp I have the code:

```
#include "ConcreteEngine3D.h"
Engine3D * engine;
...
int main(){
    engine = new ConcreteEngine3D();
    Vector3D* vector = new Vector3D(engine, 10, 5, 2);
}
```

**I want the variable `vector` be of type `ConcreteVector3D*`.**

I will need that type in `ConcreteEngine3D`, but in main.cpp I shouldn't even know it's that type and don't have to use extended fields like `length`. Also, I can't use in main.cpp anything specifically from ConcreteEngine3D.h (only Engine3D.h) - it's for the flexibly, changing the implementation must means only changing the inclusion and line with `new ConcreteEngine3D()`.

**I do not want to modify that code above or original headers from `Engine3D`.**

In the constructor of `Vector3D` I always put a pointer to `Engine3D` object (and I give here `ConcreteEngine3D` type).

**Maybe can I do something in the constructor of `Vector3D` to change the type of it?**

For example call `Vector3D* Engine3D::convert(Vector3D v)` inside of the constructor which will be inherited from `Engine3D` in `ConcreteEngine3D` (which creates a new `ConcreteVector3D` object with fields from `Vector3D` and returns it).

Of course that code doesn't work:

```
Vector3D::Vector3D(Engine3D *engine){
    //how to 'return' or 'convert' the type to the one that returns engine->convert(this);
}
```

So basically, I want to get the effect of code below but without the line `vector = engine->convert(vector)` or `Vector3D* vector2 = new ConcreteVector3D(engine, 10, 5, 2)`.

```
#include "ConcreteEngine3D.h"
Engine3D * engine;
...
int main(){
    engine = new ConcreteEngine3D();
    Vector3D* vector = new Vector3D(engine, 10, 5, 2); //produces Vector3D, not ConcreteVector3D
    vector = engine->convert(vector); //cannot be here! but creates the right object
    Vector3D* vector2 = new ConcreteVector3D(engine, 10, 5, 2); //also creates rights object, but cannot be here!
}
```

Also, I don't want to use factory in `Engine3D` or `ConcreteEngine3D`. I want to allow the 'user' create `Vector3D` just the way I have written in the first code.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to write out a working mini-program demonstrating the problem.  It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And right now you're assigning pointers to values (`Vector3D vector = new Vector3D...`) which shouldn't compile.

Comment: You can override `Vector3D`'s `operator new` to have it allocate `sizeof(ConcreteVector3D)`. Then, in Vector3D, create a `ConcreteVector3D` and `memcpy(this,...)`. But that would be awful. You're not going to help your user with such surprises - read about the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). I suggest you reconsider using a factory - have a `Vector3D* GetVector3D()` method. Define it on a separate cpp file, and have it return a pointer to a `ConcreteVector3D` object. This way, you'll have no dependencies on `ConcreteVector3D`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you would want to  use abstract factory pattern to instantiate your objects so that you would not have to directly call constructors of the concrete classes. Then, in case you would want to change the concrete types that implement your interfaces, you would only need to either link in a different implementation of your  abstracy factory, or select a proper factory implementation at run time.

Edit: Missed the "don't want to use factory"... Anyway you will need some kind of redirection, because constructor will return the type you instantiate. Closest you can get is probably creating a static factory method "create" to class Vector3D that returns a pointer to Vector3D, but internally creates an instance of concrete implementation class. In case you do that, it is good practice to make the constructor of Vector3D private to prevent creating the vector in "wrong way".

Comment: _"Also, I don't want to use factory..."_ :)

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about it. Unfortunately that will make me to use Vector3D v = MyFactory::create(), instead of constructor. Isn't there any way to use it instead?

Comment: @PolGraphic If you wont make any modifications to the first sample code it is impossible to do what you are trying to achieve. A factory is the proper solution.  Constructors are not polymorphic. They will always construct what they tell you they will construct.

Comment: +1 for factory. "Don't want to use Factory" is a bad argument (unjustified). Getting hung up on syntax is just paiting yourself in a corner.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Tomazos, about the not clear writting - Sorry for that :/

I must agree with Captain Giraffe, that I cannot achieve it without **any** changes in main.cpp. I used the a little modified factory pattern:

I had to made Vector3D::create() static function which will call Engine3D::convert() and returns it's result. So the code will be:

```
#include "ConcreteEngine3D.h"
Engine3D * engine;
...
int main(){
    engine = new ConcreteEngine3D();
    Vector3D vector = Vector3D::create(engine, 10, 5, 2);
}
```

Inside of Vector3D::create:

return engine->convert(new Vector3D(x,y,z));

Which will produce ConcreteVector3D (because engine is of type ConcreteEngine3D).

Minimal changes in main.cpp, acceptable (no ConcreteVector3D mentioned in the main.cpp).

Once more, **thanks for help, to all of you!** :-)

Comment: Sure, thanks. I have forgotten it first, but now I have accepted the anserw from you.